# Scifi Anthology from 70s: Enchanted Village w/ cover image of floating rock ("The Castle" by Magritte)

Tags: story-identification, anthology-book

I checked this book out of a library in the 70's, so it might  be from earlier.

I remember the "Enchanted Village" story by Van Vogt, and the cover image of a floating rock. I think it was "The Castle of the Pyrenees" by Magritte, or something similar.

Would love to find it or its equivalent with any cover to remember the rest of the stories in it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You can check out [the covers of all the books that include "Enchanted Village"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?56655) on ISFDb; to me it doesn't look like any of them have a cover matching ["The Castle of the Pyrenees"](https://www.renemagritte.org/the-castle-of-the-pyrenees.jsp), but you might recognise one of the others.

Answer (score 11):

Given your description of the cover the anthology surely has to be [The Far-Out Worlds of A. E. van Vogt](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2012407.The_Far_Out_Worlds_of_A_E_van_Vogt) but this doesn't contain Enchanted Village.

[image: The Far-Out Worlds of A. E. van Vogt]

Is it possible you've mixed up your van Vogt anthologies?

Answer (score 3):

Could it be the short story collection ['Innocents Aboard'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Innocents_Aboard) by Gene Wolfe?

[image: Cover image]

Unfortunately, it wasn't published until 2004 so unless you're wrong about when you read it, it's unlikely to be the one you remember. However, it does feature the Magritte painting you referenced.

Comment: Also used for a [1974 collection](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?797449) of Kafka stories, but since neither includes the mentioned story (or any by van Vogt at all) I didn't think it was really worth mentioning.

Comment: @DavidW: Technically, not a collection of Kafka stories, but just his novel _The Castle_, with fragments and variants.

Comment: @DaG Ah, right.  I wasn't paying enough attention to the page numbers. :)